# RocksDBStateBackend in Flink: how does it works exactly?

Tags: apache-flink, rocksdb

I have read the official Flink's documentation about the State Backends, [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/ops/state/state_backends.html). In particular, I was interested in the *RocksDBStateBackend*.

I don't understand, if I enable this kind of backend, RocksDB will be accessible from *TaskManagers* through another node inside the Flink's cluster?

What I have understood so far about the RocksDBStateBackend is that Task Managers will store the states inside their memory, i.e. the memory of the JVM process. After that, will they send the states to store inside RocksDB? If yes, where is RocksDB inside the Flink's cluster? Where is it phisically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

RocksDB is an embedded database. If you are using RocksDB as your state backend for Flink, then each task manager has a local instance of RocksDB, which runs as a native (JNI) library inside the JVM. When using RocksDB, your state lives as serialized bytes on the local disk, with an in-memory (off-heap) cache.

During checkpointing, the SST files from RocksDB are copied from the local disk to the distributed file system where the checkpoint is stored. If the local recovery option is enabled, then a local copy is retained as well, to speed up recovery. But it wouldn't be safe to rely only on the local copy, as the local disk might be lost if the node fails. This is why checkpoints are always stored on a distributed file system.

The alternative to RocksDB is to use one of the heap-based state backends, in which case your state will live as objects on the JVM heap.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Still a doubt: when a TM process does a checkpoint, it sends the ack to the JM, together with the "pointer" of the stored checkpoint inside the disk. Then, the JM puts the pointer inside the "checkpoint object". So, if each TM contains different local instances of RocksDB, the JM cannot send to a TM the pointer to a checkpoint saved from another TM? This might be useful in case of fault recovery.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some info about rocksdb and checkpointing.

Comment: Thank you David, you're really helping me. So, if you set RocksDB as backend you must also configure a distributed file system? I thought this was necessary just if you wanted to use the FsStateBackend. Am I wrong?

Comment: See my further update. But yes, a distributed file system is always needed.

Comment: Thank you David, my last question, if you can: As a storage system, instead of a distributed FS, can i configure an external DBMS, for example?

Comment: No, that won't work, or least not without doing a lot of work. You would need to implement the interface described here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/filesystems/#adding-a-new-pluggable-file-system-implementation